# Javascript REST API Post Form

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

I am new to REST and I am trying to add a variable to the JSON body so I can have an input form for the values.

I have also tried using getElementID along with this HTML form after wrapping the the script in a function, but I am having no success.

```
    var requestBody = "{'companyid':'getElementById('companyid')','knowledgeid':'getElementById('knowledgeid')','source_code':'getElementById('source')','article_title':'getElementById('title')'}"; 

var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("post","<URL>");

client.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json'); 
client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+btoa('admin'+':'+'admin'));

client.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(this.readyState = this.DONE) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=this.status + this.response; 
    }

}; 
client.send(requestBody);
```

Here is the form:

```
<form enctype="application/json" action="<URL>" method="post">
Title:<input id="title" type="text"></input>
Company:<input id="companyid" type="text"></input>
KnowledgeID:<input id="knowledgeid" type="text"></input>
HTML:<input id="source" type="text" ></input>


<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="restRequest()"></input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining the value of `requestBody` you don't want to get the element itself, but it's value. You also have that single quoted so it's not going to get evaluated.

```
var requestBody = "{'companyid': '" + document.getElementById('companyid').value + "', 'knowledgeid': '" + document.getElementById('knowledgeid').value + "', 'source_code': '" + document.getElementById('source').value + "', 'article_title': '" + document.getElementById('title').value + "'}";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to be careful when constructing a body use proper concatenations see following with alertbox

```
var requestBody = "{companyid: " + document.getElementById(companyid).value + ", knowledgeid: " + document.getElementById(knowledgeid).value + ", source_code: " + document.getElementById(source).value + ", article_title: " + document.getElementById(title).value + "}";

alert(requestBody);
```

I will recommend take some time and look at JQuery framework. It will make your life lot easier